# foreach object looping adding on top of the stack

Tags: javascript, object, loops, addition

I have an js, object which is something like this:

```
function test{
this.variable = {};
this.populate = function(){
  // do some crap....
  // and i populate the object like this
  this.variable{xyz..} = new object();
}
this.outputThecrap(){
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     if(data[key].idParent != '0'){
            //do some stuff
     } 
     }
  }
}
this.addSomeOnBeginigQQ(){
  // how do i do that!!!!Q_Q
  this.variable{blabla...} = new blabla();
}
}
```

now after I populate the object like

```
var t = new test();
t.populate();
t.addSomeOnBegining();
t.outputThecrap();
```

I get the problem that the added properties wind up on the end of the loop ... and I need them to be on the top

Anyone has some idea how to solve this?

UPDATE:

The structure of the object is not open to change. i cant use the  array as a container either, that s out of question.

Comment: Use an array? The iteration order of object properties is not guaranteed to be in some particular order.

Comment: What is `data`? Also, I hope your `populate` function is only intended to be pseudo code, there are lots of syntax problems

Comment: it is pseudo giberish. And th eobject is in reallity a dom object so the order is guarantied when i loop trough them.

Comment: You should not extend DOM objects with custom properties - and no, they still have no order. Please show us what exactly you are doing with your real code

Comment: sorry cant do that that is company propertyl..... and it is like 2k lines of js.... sooo :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a stack, you will need to use an `Array` - a list with a defined order. Object properties have none in JavaScript, there is nothing like "associative arrays". Also, you should the prototype.

You can set properties of array just as you do with objects, but the property names need to be numerically (i.e. integers). You then loop over them with a `for`-loop. [`Array` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) also have some extra methods, for example to add items in the beginning or the end (which I have used below):

```
function Test() {
    this.data = []; // an array
}
Test.prototype.populate = function(){
    // populate the array like this
    this.data.push({…});
};
Test.prototype.outputThecrap = function(){
    for (var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++) {
        var item = this.data[i];
        if (item /* has the right properties*/)
             //do some stuff
    } 
};
Test.prototype.addSomeOnBeginning(){
    this.data.unshift({…});
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
var t = new Test();
t.populate();
t.addSomeOnBeginning();
t.outputThecrap();
```

---

The "ordered key array" looks like this:

```
function Test() {
    this.data = {}; // the object
    this.order = []; // an array
}
Test.prototype.populate = function(){
    this.data["something"] = {…}
    this.order.push("something");
};
Test.prototype.addSomeOnBeginning(){
    this.data["other"] = {…};
    this.order.unshift("other");
};
Test.prototype.outputThecrap = function(){
    for (var i=0; i<this.order.length; i++) {
        var key = this.order[i],
            item = this.data[key];
        if (item && key /* fulfill your requirements */)
             // do some stuff
    } 
};
```

Comment: This is of no use to me. i forgoto to mention i cant use array like you do becouse my object do have to be ordered, but contain certain names which are ordered. so i cant really use your metod.

Comment: @Sangoku: What about an array of (ordered) keys? That way, you can keep your current property design and define the order of the keys through that array.

Comment: i cant. the whole code is made on a singleton desighn 
so i have to make available somthing like this 
object[someid].someproperty.function(); 
and i need to make it possible to loop trough the object.

Comment: Then you need an extra array of the object keys, which you can sort as you like

Comment: I found the solution, jquery has the extend function, which i needed for my work ;D

Comment: @pimvdb well i didn not want to have to relay on that as a meter of fact i could have but i did not want to :P... to much hassle...